# Android, how to get parent process id

Tags: android

On Android device , given a process id, I want to programatically find
the parent process ID.
I have searched a lot but unable to find the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can try `int ppid = android.os.Process.myPpid()`

Comment: As per the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process#myPid()) there is no method as `myPpid()` in `android.os.process`. Moreover `myPid()` doesn't gives the id of the parent process, but the process itself.

Comment: What about ```int ppid = android.system.Os.getppid()``` ?

Comment: If you are referring to [AOSP's source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/os/Process.java) , then the `getppid()` has been annotated with `UnsupportedAppUsage` that means it is not available in the Android SDK.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Runtime`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runtime) to execute a command on the command line and get the parent process id (PPID).

By executing the `ps -o ppid= $pid` command, [you can get the PPID](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153976/how-do-i-get-the-parent-process-id-of-a-given-child-process) of the process id passed in as `$pid`.

Here's an example in Kotin:

```
val pid = android.os.Process.myPid()
val command = "ps -o ppid= $pid"
val p =  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
val bufferedReader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()))
val result = bufferedReader.readText().trim().toInt()
```

### Edit:

@GreenFeel's comment on their answer describes a simpler way using `android.system.Os.getppid()`.